# Windows 10 Firewall Blocking Firefox?

Tags: firefox, windows-firewall

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but Firefox (or internet connection) is running really slow on my new laptop. I was in my firewall and saw that it's blocking the program. Obviously, Firefox is still working because I'm using it right now, but should I remove these firewall rules? Would it make it run faster?

Firefox has the latest update and so does Windows.

Thank you!

Comment: No, I didn't make them. I can't tell if you're being serious or not. Should I really delete them?

Comment: If you think that those rules are made somehow and are associate with Firefox then it is obvious to delete them seriously.